# Overriding environment values via .env.local

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[By default we can set default values in an environment file named `.env`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file).

I would like to know if there is a simple way to use a `.env.local` for example to override an environment value.

I know I can use `docker-compose.override.yaml` but the key `env_file` must be in all containers:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  php:
    env_file:
      - ./.env.local
  nginx:
    env_file:
      - ./.env.local
```

But this is not really a elegant way because I use a file (`docker-compose.override.yaml`) to tell it to use this file (`./.env.local`).

Another things of course is to fullfill `docker-compose.override.yaml` with directly values:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  php:
    build:
      args:
        HTTP_PROXY: ''
        NO_PROXY: ''
    environment:
      XDEBUG: 1
  nginx:
    build:
      args:
        UPSTREAM: 'php:9000'
```

This works really well but it is not really an easiest way to override keys for anyone has just beginning in Docker.

Have you an idea to have a simple way like `.env` for overriding value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this by using the `--env-file <path to env file>` option for `docker-compose`

Eg: To demonstrate what I mean, I put together a small demo,

I've made a docker-compose file with 1 service - test that builds an image from alpine and instructs the container to `printenv` when it starts.

[image: file structure]

Then I went ahead and ran this, first with no --env-file to demonstrate that by default docker-compose picks up values in .env file, then with the --env-file option to demonstrate the override.

[image: using --env-file]

Comment: Thanks I've seen that already before but this was same things to me. So I decided to use my makefile to select automatically the correct file.

```
ENV_FILE  = .env
ifneq ("$(wildcard .env.local)","")
    ENV_FILE = .env.local
endif

DOCKER_COMPOSE  = docker-compose --env-file=${ENV_FILE}
```

It is not perfect because best things should merge both files, but it is another things.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I posted my solution because it can be useful for someone.
Docker-compose.yml allows you to specify the `env_file` key for service.
And it can be an array, so you can use two (or more) files, and if these files have the same variables values will be used from the last one:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app: &app
    build:
      context: .
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
    env_file:
      - .env.development
      - .env.development.local
```